# pacemaker create resource systemd & haproxy

Tags: redhat, haproxy, high-availability, pacemaker

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
# 
# rpm -q pacemaker
pacemaker-1.1.16-12.el7_4.7.x86_64
#
```

I'm trying to create *systemd* resource, however Pacemaker isn't even showing `haproxy` in the list:

```
# systemctl status haproxy
● haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
#
# pcs resource agents systemd | grep haproxy
#
```

however, if I go ahead and create it anyway, resource seems fine:

```
# pcs resource create haproxy systemd:haproxy
# pcs resource show haproxy 
 Resource: haproxy (class=systemd type=haproxy)
  Operations: monitor interval=60 timeout=100 (haproxy-monitor-interval-60)
              start interval=0s timeout=100 (haproxy-start-interval-0s)
              stop interval=0s timeout=100 (haproxy-stop-interval-0s)
#
```

Is that normal? or am I doing something wrong?

Please advise.

Comment: That looks normal to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's all right. If you want to check the standards of pacemaker then you can check with this command "pcs resource standards" this command will show the list of standards which are compatible with pacemaker.